# Why is my custom MSBuild script not able to copy project references when invoked from Visual Studio?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, deployment, msbuild, wix

I am trying to simplify the deployment for one of our web projects by supplying an installer that takes care of everything the application needs to be initialized. I've chosen the [WiX toolset](http://wixtoolset.org/) for this and created a custom build script following [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/115036/Creating-WIX-Installer-for-ASP-NET-Web-Application) and partly [this tutorial](http://blog.bartdemeyer.be/2013/10/create-an-installer-for-website-with-wix-part-1/). To reproduce the problem I am facing, you can download the sources of the first tutorial link.

My general goal is to be able to create an installer directly from Visual Studio. The tutorial describes how to write a build script that generates the installer. Basically I want to invoke this script by clicking "Build" within Visual Studio (2012, if it matters).

First I've added a WiX project to the solution (relocate it to the *setup*-directory!). I've added all the setup-files and the required WiX references (UI, Util, IIS, SQL). By simply invoking the build now, WiX complains about an undefined `var.publishDir` variable. So I ran the supplied build script using the following command inside the VS developer console:

```
msbuild /t:Build;CreateInstaller;DeleteTmpFiles build_setup.build
```

First this gave me an error 9009 (command not found) when trying to invoke the heat tool for harvesting. I fixed this by replacing the `"$(WixPath)heat"` call with `"$(WiX)\bin\heat"`. After that everything worked as desired, so I started hooking into the build process of the `.wixproj` file in order to call the build script from there. I did this by defining the following build targets (right below the item groups):

```
<Target Name="Build">
  <MSBuild Projects="build_setup.build" Targets="Build;CreateInstaller" Properties="" />
</Target>
<Target Name="Rebuild">
  <MSBuild Projects="build_setup.build" Targets="Build;CreateInstaller;DeleteTmpFiles" Properties="" />
</Target>
<Target Name="Clean">
  <MSBuild Projects="build_setup.build" Targets="DeleteTmpFiles" Properties="" />
</Target>
```

Also I checked, if the installer project is excluded from solution-wide builds inside the build configuration manager for all configurations (but especially `Release|AnyCPU` since this is the desired configuration for deployment). For sake of clarity I've fixed both MSBuild calls within the *build_setup.build* script and added my desired platform:

```
<!-- Define default target with name 'Build' -->
<Target Name="Build">
  <!-- Compile whole solution in release mode -->
  <MSBuild Projects="..\MyWeb\MyWeb.sln" Targets="ReBuild"
      Properties="Configuration=Release;Platform=Any CPU" />
</Target>

<!-- Define creating installer in another target -->
<Target Name="CreateInstaller">
  <RemoveDir Directories="$(PublishF)" ContinueOnError="false" />
  <MSBuild Projects="..\MyWeb\MyWeb\MyWeb.csproj" Targets="ResolveReferences;_CopyWebApplication"
      Properties="OutDir=$(Publish)bin\;WebProjectOutputDir=$(Publish);Configuration=Release;Platform=AnyCPU" />
  <!-- ... -->
</Target>
```

Now when I invoke the build by right-clicking the installer project and "Build", the build is successfully triggered from Visual Studio - exactly what I want.

The problem begins with adding project references: I've added a new library project (defined a simple class in there, referenced the library from the website and created an instance of the library class there). As soon as I try to build the project from Visual Studio now, I get an error that the referenced assembly cannot be copied *from* the publish-directory, because it does not exist:

> Microsoft.WebApplication.targets(175,5): error MSB3030: Could not copy file "...\WixWebDeploy\Setup\publish\bin\MyWeb.Model.dll" because it was not found.

The strange thing is, that everything works fine, if I invoke the build script from the developer console! Also this only affects project references (the project is published using the targets `ResolveReferences` and `_CopyWebApplication`). NuGet packages or static library references are copied without any problems.

I appreciate any ideas that point me into the right direction to tackle down this issue. For example I am interested in the difference between calling msbuild from console or Visual Studio (if there is any...). Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out how to fix this issue. The solution was to <s>use `OutputPath` argument instead of `OutDir`</s> call a command line script from MSBuild:

```
<Target Name="Build">
  <Exec Command="echo Building solution with '$(MSBuildToolsPath)\msbuild'..." />
  <!--<MSBuild Projects="build_setup.build" Targets="CreateInstaller" Properties="Configuration=Release;Platform=AnyCPU" />-->
  <Exec Command="call build_setup.cmd $(MSBuildToolsPath) CreateInstaller" />
</Target>
<Target Name="Rebuild">
  <Exec Command="echo Building solution with '$(MSBuildToolsPath)\msbuild'..." />
  <!--<MSBuild Projects="build_setup.build" Targets="Build;CreateInstaller" Properties="" />-->
  <Exec Command="call build_setup.cmd $(MSBuildToolsPath) Build CreateInstaller" />
</Target>
<Target Name="Clean">
  <Exec Command="echo Building solution with '$(MSBuildToolsPath)\msbuild'..." />
  <!--<MSBuild Projects="build_setup.build" Targets="DeleteTmpFiles" Properties="" />-->
  <Exec Command="call build_setup.cmd $(MSBuildToolsPath) DeleteTmpFiles" />
</Target>
```

From the *build_setup.cmd* I call MSBuild again:

```
if [%1] == [] (
    echo "Please supply the msbuild directory as first argument!"
    exit 10
) else (
    set MSBUildDir=%1
)

if [%2] == [] (
    echo "You have to supply at least one of the following arguments: Build, CreateInstaller, DeleteTmpFiles!"
    exit 11
) else if [%3] == [] (
    echo "%MSBUildDir%\msbuild /t:%2 setup.build"
    call %MSBUildDir%\msbuild /t:%2 setup.build
    exit 0
) else if [%4] == [] (
    echo "%MSBUildDir%\msbuild /t:%2;%3 setup.build"
    call %MSBUildDir%\msbuild /t:%2;%3 setup.build
    exit 0
) else (
    echo "%MSBUildDir%\msbuild /t:%2;%3;%4 setup.build"
    call %MSBUildDir%\msbuild /t:%2;%3;%4 setup.build
    exit 0
)
```

This seams kinda redundant and maybe somebody got a better suggestion.